# Delete an accepted correct-answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I voted to close as a dupe/too localized and then answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364460/string-to-nsdate-format/15364788#15364788).

My solution is correct, It got +1/-4 but OP accepted it. the comments on my answers are saying you should not answer a dupe, or you answered and closed, so that I will earn points. Few thinking as answer is incorrect so got downvotes.

Now I want to delete the answer, I commented and asked OP to un-accept but he is not doing so, can I flag it to moderator?

Comment: Just wait until the question gets nuked.

Comment: that answer is 15 reputation points in your favor

Comment: @SamIam: Nothing to do with points, If you check my profile, i dont have any answer in negative points. However many times i got downvotes, I removed those answers :P

Comment: @SamIam If he knows that the answer shouldn't be there, and that it's better off being deleted, I think it's great that he's willing to delete it himself even though it has positive rep.  If find it unfortunate that a lot of *terrible* answers can get lots of justified downvotes but one or two pity upvotes means they get positive rep, so the owner won't delete it.

Comment: @Servy Now +5/-5 :(

Comment: Question deleted.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: thanks :) however i lost 55 points :D